# How to create Rest API for Store Wise Site Map in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, api, rest-api, sitemaps

I want to create Rest API for sitemap according to the store-wise. Which include active, salable and visible products on front-end.

Can anyone suggest? How to do that task?